# How can I know that the Firefox Developer tools are open with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I need to find a certain indications to detect whether or not Firefox Developer tools are open for the site I placed in. It has to be done with vanilla JS in the client side scope.

I found many indications for Chrome browser, but couldn't find even one stable way for Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510212/how-do-you-detect-if-firefox-devtools-is-open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if browser console / inspector is \*open\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507780/how-to-detect-if-browser-console-inspector-is-open)

Comment: Unfortunately no.. The scenario there is different than mine, and I did found a way to detect it on Chrome..

Comment: My first link is almost an exact duplicate of this question. That was flagged as a duplicate of the other one. What makes yours different?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The answers there focused on how to hide the client source code from the end user, where my need is totally different

Comment: Your need might be different but the resulting question is the same. "How to detect if the dev tools are open"

Comment: In any case the answers there are not relevant though..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30715877/989920 I find this relevant